# Functions on the continuum with an unboundedness property

Tags: set-theory

Is it possible to construct bijections, $f_\alpha:2^{\aleph_0}\to 2^{\aleph_0}$, for each $\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}$ such that for each $\beta,\gamma$ there is an $\alpha$ such that $f_\alpha(\beta)>\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; here’s one simple way. Enumerate $2^\omega\times 2^\omega$ as $\{\langle\beta_\xi,\gamma_\xi\rangle:\xi<2^\omega\}$. For each $\xi<2^\omega$ define

$$f_\xi:2^\omega\to 2^\omega:\alpha\mapsto\begin{cases}
\gamma_\xi+1,&\text{if }\alpha=\beta_\xi\\
\beta_\xi,&\text{if }\alpha=\gamma_\xi+1\\
\alpha,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

That is, $f_\xi$ is the permutation of $2^\omega$ that interchanges $\beta_\xi$ and $\gamma_\xi+1$.